# Custom validation in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have a Page object that contains a Metadata property like this

```
public class Page {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public Metadata Metadata { get; set; }
}

public class Metadata {
    public string Slug { get; set; }
}
```

when I save my page I need to verify that no other page with the same parent has the same slug. I was thinking about using a validation attribute on the slug property but when I do that I'm not able to find the page object. What is the best approach of validating such things?

Answer (score 0):

If you insist upon using data annotations validation attributes, you could get access to all of the properties by putting the attribute on the Page class rather than the Slug property.

However [there is something better](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CreatingAValidator&referringTitle=Documentation&ANCHOR#ReusingValidators).